# Writing rows in columns in txt python

Tags: python, txt

I have txt file like this:

```
Name  |  Class  |  Points
--------------------------
Name1 |    (2)  |  30
Name1 |    (3)  |  50
Name1 |    (5)  |  15
Name2 |    (1)  |  25
Name2 |    (3)  |  88
Name2 |    (4)  |  3
```

There are 100 unique values under the column `class`: `[(1), (2), (3), ..., (100)]`

I would like to populate the values based on the `class` value, so the new table will have the **classes** as the columns like this:

```
      |  (1)  |   (2)  |  (3) | (4) | (5) |...
----------------------------------------------
Name1 |       |  30    |  50  |     | 15  |
Name2 |   25  |        |  88  |  3  |     |
```

Explanation for `Name1`:

> In the first table (the original format from the file), the `Name1` has **30** points for class `(2)`, **50** points for class `(3)`, and **15** points for class `(5)`

Comment: Could you be more specific on your intentions? What exact result are you looking for?

Comment: Could you provide at least a screenshot of sample data and output that you would like

Comment: Have you looked at the python csv reader and tried to bring the text file into python? You can use the | as delimiters to separate your data.

Comment: What he you tried so far?

Comment: Changing it to CSV makes it easier to read and also for the further process

Answer (score 0):

So far I have this:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
classes = set()
names = set()
for line in f:
    line = line.split("\t")
    if line[1] == "Class":
        continue
    else:
        classes.add(int(line[1]))
    names.add(line[0])
sorted(classes)
print(classes)
with open("new_file.txt", "a") as f:
    for i in classes:
        f.write(f"\t{i}")
    for j in names:
        f.write(f"\n{j}")
```

Comment: Did you have any problems with this code?